# If I use content from one domain on my other domain, but spread it - how do I implement the canoncial tag?

Tags: duplicate-content, ranking, rel-canonical, pagination

I used the content of one of my domains (`nameA.example/ContentA`) and copied it to another domain, but on several pages:

- `nameB.example/ContentA1`
- `nameB.example/ContentA2`
- `nameB.example/ContentA3`
- and so on

So I divided the content from domainA to several pages of domainB.
The reason is, that my client wants to build a new business on domainB and wants to use the exact same content from domainA, because he can't afford another copywriter at the moment (and he doesn't want to rewrite it himself).

Problem: DomainA is ranking for this content and he wants to keep the rankings, until domainB ranks similar (for the same keywords, of course).

Can I put a canonical tag on domainA? 
My thoughts are: Not a single page of domainB is 100% duplicate content, as it's always only partially the same.
Can I just choose one of those pages from domainB to put as link-goal for the canonical tag?

Or do I need to create a "view-all" page on domainB, with all the content put together, so it's 100% duplicate to domainA, and then put a canonical tag to domainA and link to this "view-all" page?

If I do so, do I need to also put canonicals on every single page from domainB, to link to this "view-all" page? 
IMPORTANT: Would the other pages of domainB then be ranked/listed in the SERRPs, or only the "view-all" site?